Button on one menu click on another screen
type here
When clicking my play button on my main menu it changes the screen and clicks the paper button on the play screen. My instructor and I are both have issues solving the problem of clicking buttons on both screens. Any help would be helpful. Thank you.
When I click play on the main menu if should change to the play screen and wait for another click.
GUI code. I have included all the code to make the program work.
The code below is for the GUI of the program. It loads a Main Menu with three (3) buttons. All the button work as they should, however, when I click the play button it changes the screens as it should to the play  screen but it also clicks the paper button on the play screen. I did not include the image files or font files.
# Game Imports. 
import pygame, sys, code_classes, button, time

# Initializes pygame.
pygame.init()

# Variables that set windows Width and Height
WINDOW_WIDTH = 800
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 550

fps = 30 
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Sets the fonts for pygame. 
title_font = pygame.font.Font('fonts/campus.ttf', 25)
title_bf = pygame.font.Font('fonts/college.ttf', 20)
game_bf = pygame.font.Font('fonts/collegeb.ttf', 30)
socre_font = pygame.font.Font('fonts/CollegiateFLF.ttf', 20)

# Loads the images for background and buttons.
icon = pygame.image.load('photo/icon.png')
play = pygame.image.load('photo/play_button.png')
play_again = pygame.image.load('photo/play_again.png')
main_menu = pygame.image.load('photo/main_menu.png')
directions = pygame.image.load('photo/directions_button.png')
exit_img = pygame.image.load('photo/exit_button.png')
background = pygame.image.load('photo/enterprise.png')
rock = pygame.image.load('photo/rock.jpg')
paper = pygame.image.load('photo/paper.jpg')
scissors = pygame.image.load('photo/scissors.png')
lizard = pygame.image.load('photo/lizard.jpg')
spock = pygame.image.load('photo/spock.jpg')

# Sets the colors for pygame. 
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
gray = (113, 121, 126)
green = (170, 255, 0)

# Creates Buttons.
play_button = button.Button(375, 175, play, .35)
info_button = button.Button(375, 250, directions, .35)
exit_button = button.Button(375, 325, exit_img, .35)
exit_button1 = button.Button(126, 505, exit_img, .30)
play_again_button = button.Button(251, 505, play_again, .30)
main_menu_button = button.Button(1, 505, main_menu, .30)
rock_button = button.Button(150, 100, rock, .15)
paper_button = button.Button(275, 100, paper, .35)
scissors_button = button.Button(525, 100, scissors, .68)
lizard_button = button.Button(185, 250, lizard, .20)
spock_button = button.Button(450, 250, spock, .17)

# Creates the window and sets the window title. 
window = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Main Menu")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# game window control. 
window_state = 'main'

# player selection.
player = ''
code_classes.users_choise = player


# Fuction to draw text on screen.
def show_text(text, font, text_color, x, y):
    text_img = font.render(text, True, text_color)
    window.blit(text_img, (x, y))

# main game loop.
app = True # Sets the varabile app to True.
while app: # Creates a while loop.
    # fills the root_window with black.
    window.fill('black')
    window.blit(background, (0, 0))
    clock.tick(fps)

    # chech game state.
    if window_state == 'main': # if window_state varabile is 'main' run code below.
        show_text('Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock', title_font, green, 180, 10) # Puts text on the screen.
        show_text('Please make a selection', title_font, green, 255, 40) # Puts text on the screen.
        if play_button.draw_button(window): # Puts button on screen.
            #time.sleep(.5)
            window_state = 'play' # Changes the window_state varabile to 'play'
        if info_button.draw_button(window): # Puts button on screen.
            window_state = 'info' # Changes the window_state varabile to 'info'
        if exit_button.draw_button(window): # Puts button on screen.
            app = False # Sets the varabile app to False and close the while loop exiting the game.
    if window_state == 'play': # if window_state varabile is 'main' run code below.
        player_choise = ''
        show_text('Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock', title_font, green, 180, 10) # Puts text on the screen.
        show_text('Please make a selection', title_font, green, 255, 40) # Puts text on the screen.
        show_text(f'Score = {code_classes.score_str()}', socre_font, green, 650, 510) # Puts text on the screen.
        show_text(f'{code_classes.statement}', game_bf, green,300, 375)
        if main_menu_button.draw_button(window): # Puts button on screen.
            window_state = 'main' # Changes the window_state varabile to 'main'
        if exit_button1.draw_button(window): # Puts button on screen.
           app = False # Sets the varabile app to False and close the while loop exiting the game.
           sys.exit()
        if rock_button.draw_button(window): # Puts button on screen.
            player_choise = 'Rock'
            print('Rock')
        if paper_button.draw_button(window): # Puts button on screen.
            player_choise = 'Paper'
            print('Paper')
        if scissors_button.draw_button(window): # Puts button on screen.
            player_choise = 'Scissors'
            print('Scissors')
        if lizard_button.draw_button(window): # Puts button on screen.
            player_choise = 'Lizard'
            print('Lizard')
        if spock_button.draw_button(window): # Puts button on screen.
            player_choise = 'Spock'
            print('Spock')
        if player_choise:
            computer_choise = code_classes.pick()
            check_win = code_classes.Check_Win(player_choise, computer_choise)
            winner = check_win.player_Win()
            check_win.add_score(winner)
            statement = check_win.statments_to_return(winner)
            player_choise = ''

    if window_state == 'info': # if window_state varabile is 'main' run code below.
        show_text('Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock', title_font, green, 180, 10) # Puts text on the screen.
        show_text('THE RULES ARE AS FOLLOWS:', title_font, green, 250, 80) # Puts text on the screen.
        show_text('The user will pick one of the following: Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard or Spock.', title_bf, green, 25, 110) # Puts text on the screen.
        show_text('The computer will than randomly make a choise.', title_bf, green, 175, 130) # Puts text on the screen.
        show_text('HOW TO WIN:', title_font, green, 325, 200) # Puts text on the screen.
        show_text('Rock beats scissors and lizard.', title_bf, green, 250, 220) # Puts text on the screen.
        show_text('Paper beats rock and disproves Spock.', title_bf, green, 225, 240) # Puts text on the screen.
        show_text('Scissors cuts paper and decapitates lizard.', title_bf, green, 200, 260) # Puts text on the screen.
        show_text('Lizard eats paper and poisons Spock.', title_bf, green, 225, 280) # Puts text on the screen.
        show_text('Spock vaporizes rock and smashes scissors.', title_bf, green, 200, 300) # Puts text on the screen.
        if main_menu_button.draw_button(window): # Puts button on screen.
            window_state = 'main' # Changes the window_state varabile to 'main'
        if exit_button1.draw_button(window): # Puts button on screen.
            app = False # Sets the varabile app to False and close the while loop exiting the game.
            sys.exit()
    # handles events
    for event in pygame.event.get(): # Looks for and get events from pygame.
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If the event is equal to pygame quit event exacute code below.
            app = False # Sets the varabile app to False and close the while loop exiting the game.

    # updates the game window.
    pygame.display.update() #update game display

# Quits pygame when loop exits. 
pygame.quit()

Below is the code I use to create the buttons. This class is imported to the GUI.py.
# Game Imports. 
import pygame
# Creats a class for making a button in pygame.
class Button:
    def __init__(self, x, y, image, scale):
        # Gets the image width and set it to variable image_width
        image_width = image.get_width()
        # Gets the image height and set it to variable image_height
        image_height = image.get_height()
        # Sets the scale of the image using transform.scale by multipling the image varables by a decimal and asigns the image to a variable image.
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (int(image_width * scale), int(image_height * scale))) # You have to set your math to an int pygame will crash if your code returns a float.
        # Sets the image on a pygame rect object.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        # Sets the top left conor of the rect object to x, y position.
        self.rect.topleft = (x, y)
        # Sets the button clicked value to False (button clicked off).
        self. clicked = False

    # Defines a new fuction under the Button class.
    def draw_button(self, surface):
        action = False
        # Gets the mouse positon.
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        # Checks if the mouse is over a button and in button was clicked.
        if self.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            # checks if the left [0] mouse button was clicked and only lets the button be click if clicked is False.
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1 and self.clicked == False:
                # When letf mouse button click set the click varable to True and stops the mouse from clicking again.
                self.clicked = True
                action = True
                

            # Reset the clicked varable to False when left mouse button is released.
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 0:
                self.clicked = False       

        
        # Draws the botton on the window.  
        surface.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))

        return action
    

The code below is my main game code. It does all the logic checks.
import random # This imports the module for generating random numbers.

'''Below are Varables for the game. '''
computers_choise = ''
users_choise = ''
score = 0
win = 0
statement = 'Make a Choise' 

win_statement = 'You Won'
lose_statement = 'You lost'
tie_statement = 'You have tied'

'''Below is a list of choise for the user and computer to use.'''
rpsls = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors', 'Lizard', 'Spock']

def score_str():
    score_string = str(score)
    return score_string

def pick():
    pick = random.randrange(5)
    computers_choise = rpsls[pick]
    return computers_choise

def users_choise():
    return users_choise.capitalize()

class Check_Win:
    def __init__(self, users_choise, computers_choise):
        self.computers_choise = computers_choise
        self.users_choise = users_choise

    def player_Win(self):
        win = 0
        if (self.users_choise == 'Rock'):
            if (self.computers_choise == 'Scissors'):
                win += 1
            elif (self.computers_choise == 'Lizard'):
                win += 1
            elif (self.users_choise == self.computers_choise):
                win += 1.5
        elif (self.users_choise == 'Paper'):
            if (self.computers_choise == 'Rock'):
                win += 1
            elif (self.computers_choise == 'Spock'):
                win += 1
            elif (self.users_choise == self.computers_choise):
                win += 1.5
        elif (self.users_choise == 'Scissors'):
            if (self.computers_choise == 'Paper'):
                win += 1
            elif (self.computers_choise == 'Lizard'):
                win += 1
            elif (self.users_choise == self.computers_choise):
                win += 1.5
        elif (self.users_choise == 'Lizard'):
            if (self.computers_choise == 'Paper'):
                win += 1
            elif (self.computers_choise == 'Spock'):
                win += 1
            elif (self.users_choise == self.computers_choise):
                win += 1.5
        elif (self.users_choise == 'Spock'):
            if (self.computers_choise == 'Rock'):
                win += 1
            elif (self.computers_choise == 'Scissors'):
                win += 1
            elif (self.users_choise == self.computers_choise):
                win += 1.5
            else:
                return "What the hell"       
        return win
        
    def add_score(self, win):
        global score

        self.win = win 
        if win == 1:
          score += 1
        else:
            score
        return score

    def statments_to_return(self, win):
        global statement
        self.win = win 
        if win == 1:
            win = 0
            statement = win_statement
            return statement
        elif win == 1.5:
            win = 0
            statement = tie_statement
            return statement
        else:
            statement = lose_statement
            return statement


if __name__ == '__main__': # This says if this is the main program run everything if not do not print. 
    computers_choise = pick()
    print(computers_choise)
   

I have provided all of the code because I am not sure if the issue is in GUI, main, or button.

use event.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN instead of pygame.mouse.get_pressed(). When you keep  mouse pressed then get_pressed() gives you many signals (one signal in every loop) but it sends only one event.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN

in button you should split draw_button on two functions - first which only draws but doesn't check get_pressed() - you can call it draw_button(). Second which use event to check if button was pressed - you can call it handle_events() - and it shoudl set variable in class (without drawing) which later you can use in draw_button() And later you run draw_button() in old place but handle_event() you runs in for event in pygame.event.get():

BTW: in all classes you could use the same name draw() instead of draw_button and draw_player(), etc. because later you can put all objects on list and run for-loop which will execute the same draw() for every object from list. It will no need to check if you have button or other object and run draw_button or draw_object

Shortly: you have to use event.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN instead of pygame.mouse.get_pressed() because when you keep mouse pressed then get_pressed() sends True all the time and before you release mouse button it can change screen and click object on next screen. Computer is too fast.
But event sends only one event.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN which will click only button but not object on next screen.
It may need to split draw_button into two functions:

handle_event(event) which you will run in for event in pygame.event.get(): and it will check event.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.pos to set self.clicked = True (and eventually event.MOUSEMOTION and event.pos to check if mouse hovers button and set self.hovered = True)
draw() which doesn't use get_pressed() but only self.clicked to draw clicked button, (and evetually use self.hovered to draw hovered button).

And this method you have to use for all objects - not only buttons.

Minimal working code.
Every screen draws button in the same position - and when you click button on one scene then it click only on this scene but not on other.
import pygame

# --- constants ---

FPS = 30

# --- classes ---

class Button:

    def __init__(self, x, y, image, scale):
        width, height = image.get_size()
        
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (int(width * scale), int(height * scale))) # You have to set your math to an int pygame 
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(x=x, y=y)
        
        self.image_hovered = self.image  # TODO: load different image
        self.image_clicked = self.image  # TODO: load different image
        
        self.hovered = False
        self.clicked = False


    def handle_event(self, event):
        self.clicked = False
        
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            self.hovered = self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos)
    
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            self.clicked = self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos)
            #self.clicked = self.hovered
        
        return self.clicked             

               
    def draw(self, surface):
        if self.hovered:
            image = self.image_hovered
        elif self.clicked:
            image = self.image_clicked
        else:
            image = self.image
         
        surface.blit(image, self.rect)
        
# --- functions ---

def generate_text(text, font, color='black'):
    image = font.render(text, True, color)
    rect  = image.get_rect()
    return image, rect

# --- main ---
        
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

font = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)

image_1 = pygame.Surface((300, 100))
image_1.fill('red')
text_image, text_rect = generate_text('INTRO', font)
text_rect.center = image_1.get_rect().center  # center text on image
image_1.blit(text_image, text_rect)

image_2 = pygame.Surface((300, 100))
image_2.fill('green')
text_image, text_rect = generate_text('GAME', font)
text_rect.center = image_2.get_rect().center  # center text on image
image_2.blit(text_image, text_rect)

center_x, center_y = screen_rect.center
button_1 = Button(center_x-150, center_y-50, image_1, 1)
button_2 = Button(center_x-150, center_y-50, image_2, 1)

state = 'intro'

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

app = True
while app:

    screen.fill('black')
    
    if state == 'intro':
        button_1.draw(screen)
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                app = False
                
            if button_1.handle_event(event):
                state = 'game'
        
    elif state == 'game':
        button_2.draw(screen)
                                
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                app = False
                
            if button_2.handle_event(event):
                state = 'intro'

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)
    
pygame.quit()

